# is it possible with pure css to make parent div resize to fit inline-block white-space nowrap content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to work out if there is anyway to make a parent div resize to fit content when the content is intentionally being prevented from wrapping. As an example here is a jsfiddle     [**jsfiddle.net/wtQfV**](http://jsfiddle.net/wtQfV) to illustrate my problem.

The example code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box_holder">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box_holder{
    border:1px solid red;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}

.box{
    width:30px;
    height:20px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Is there any work arounds for this or should I just accept I am chasing rainbows and I need a javascript solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make the `.box_holder` element be `inline-block` as well..

```
.box_holder{
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/wtQfV/5/

---

And if you want it to still maintain 100% width when there is room, you can add `min-width:100%` to it

```
.box_holder{
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/wtQfV/7/

Comment: You're my... lifesaver! My kids are more than grateful to you, because I can go and play with them instead of dully-looking for solution to this! :> Thanks!

Comment: @trejder lol, glad to provide some quality time for your family :p

Comment: I faced this issue only on mobile screen specially iphone, still don't know why. this trick really helped

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove the `white-space:nowrap;` in the css `.box_holder`

http://jsfiddle.net/wtQfV/4/

or add the  `display:inline-block;` on the `.box_holder`

http://jsfiddle.net/wtQfV/6/